# Specifying a relative path on a multiple site web server and localhost

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, path

I have a ASP.NET website that gets published to a web server that has multiple sites. For example:

`www.example.com/SiteA` or `www.example.com/SiteB`

Plus I also test the site locally before publishing, for example at `localhost:12345`

When I specify a path for an image, for example: `/Images/exampleImage.gif`, this works when running the site locally, since the Images folder is in the root directory. `localhost:12345/Images/exampleImage.gif` is the correct path in this case.

But when published to the web server, for example to `www.example.com/SiteA`, the same path tries to go to `www.example.com/Images/exampleImage.gif` and the image doesn't appear correctly.

Also, this is only for HTML controls, as with a ASP control, I know I can just use the tilde (`~/Images/exampleImage.gif`) and it'll know to look at the site's root directory, which is `www.example.com/SiteA/Images/exampleImage.gif`.

For my case, It'd be strongly preferred to stay with an HTML control.

Edit: The reason for this is because I have JavaScript that changes the image of a html img control based on if a div is hidden:

```
function Toggle(commId, imageId) {
    var div = document.getElementById(commId);
    var img = document.getElementById(imageId);
    if (div.style.display == 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'inline';
        img.src = "/Images/minus.gif";
    } else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
        img.src = "/Images/plus.gif";
    }
}
```

How could I get the path to the images folder, relative to the root of the site when there's folders for each site on a server, as well as still working on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know you could put embedded C# code in JavaScript, but figured it out by just doing :

```
function Toggle(commId, imageId) {
    var div = document.getElementById(commId);
    var img = document.getElementById(imageId);
    if (div.style.display == 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'inline';
        img.src = "<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/minus.gif") %>";
    } else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
        img.src = "<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/plus.gif") %>";
    }
}
```

Since the `ResolveUrl` method can take the tilde (~) for the path value and knows the websites root directory over the server's.

You can also use the embedded code with the same `ResolveUrl` method directly in the `src` attribute of the img html control (and other attributes/controls), in case anyone runs into this same issue but with just the HTML controls.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use code to do the ~/ or publish a new virtual directory called "/Images" on your server that contains the images.